# How to configure a PIC24 I/O Expansion board

Tags: io, pic, hardware-interface

I was wondering how to configure a PIC I/O Expansion board to work with a PIC microcontroller I am using?

I am using a PIC24EP512GU810 on a PIC24E USB Starter Kit [DM240012]. Because it doesn't have many I/O ports built onto it, I bought a Starter Kit I/O Expansion Board [DM320002] to expand my pins. According to the Expansion boards Documentation, the UART1 [which I am trying to use] on the Expansion board is located on the J11 Connector at pins 41, 43, 45, and 47. However, the UART is a remappable pin that my code sets to determine which PORT my UART1 pins are located on, so this mapping doesn't make send. The physical board itself also says a GND is located where pin 43 is, contradicting itself when I am reading its notes on the pin layout.

I was wondering if their was a header file or notes to configure an I/O Expansion board based on the model of PIC connected to it?

Comment: I noticed the same on my Starter Kit I/O Expansion Board, that pin 43 is grounded, making UART1 unusable.  If you can remap it, you should be able to just used port D or whatever port you choose, and ignore the UART1 specific pins on the expansion board